# Is a linear combination of two integers unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $m,n,a,a',b,b' \in \mathbb Z$ and $m \ne n$ and the following is true:
$$ma+nb=ma'+nb'$$
Then would it be correct to conclude $a=a'$ and $b=b'$? If yes, then prove it. Also, if possible, which assumptions can I remove in my hypothesis such that the conclusion still remains true?

**Edit**: If this is not true, can I add some condition in my hypothesis to make it true?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried any calculations or worked out any examples?

Comment: I can't even move my pen. No idea how to get around the proof. Bear in mind I'm just starting mathematics as a serious subject.

Comment: Well, it is number theory. Try examples of $m$ and $n$, like $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I tried. This is not true as pointed in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is **not** correct, since for each integer $k$,$$m(a+kn)+n(b-km)=ma+nb.$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Can I add something to my hypothesis to make the conclusion true? I am adding this part in the original question.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi It's possible. I don't know.

Comment: Then how do you know it's possible? Did you mean "It maybe possible"?

Comment: @SalmanQureshi Yes, I just meant that it may be possible.